# React native splash screen with gif image and button at bottom

Tags: react-native, splash-screen, react-native-cli

I want to develop a screen which will contain an Gif image and a button at bottom with text Take me to App

When click on the button it should display home page of my react native application.

If anyone has done this before please help me out

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

Create a rootStack for the app, it will contain splashScreen and your homeStack .
i your App.js do

```
const App = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({SplashScreen,HomeNavigation}));

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <App />
    );
  }
}
```